# Magento2 Customer Forget Password API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am using the magento2 core password reset api in postman but it returns false

[image]

I don't know what's the reason the customer with provided email is registered.
I have also installed the SMTP extension

Answer (score 1):

Hello Syed I have use the api for the customer reset password its working fine. Would you please find the below details.

```
Url : <base_url>/rest/V1/customers/me/password
Method : PUT
Autorization : Current_customer_token
Request Body: {
  "currentPassword": "PTest@11",
  "newPassword": "PTest@12"
}
Response : true
```

[image]
Hope this help you.
Thanks

Hello @sayed above is change password

Your request is correct and i also found the false in the resonse and i have checked the log and we found the SMTP Issue in log so please review your log.
Thanks

Comment: @sagar  basically i want to use forget password api, the above api is for reset

Comment: @SyedHassanZamir 
Sorry I have share the change password:
Please check your log the error are in log. first up all clear you cache and then try.
I think you email are not trigger so it will return false.

Comment: yes it is giving error in sending email, Next Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException: Unable to send mail. Please try again later. in /var/www/html/m244/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php:114

Comment: How to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

SMTP extension was having some compatability issue with magento 2.4.4, use it with magento 2.4.2 it is working fine